# Should I use existing questions to "ask new ones" when in a question ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

So maybe this is obvious, but if I'm in a question ban and I can't ask new questions yet still have things I would like to know about, should I edit the old questions I have and completely replace them with brand new questions?  That sounds like the best way to "edit my existing questions" because in retrospect some of the things I asked have pretty obvious answers or nonsensical, unhelpful solutions.

**Edit:** I'm not trying to break the system.  I'm trying to honestly, legitimately get out of a question ban.  I feel like some of my questions are irrecoverable in their current state, which is why I asked first if it would be acceptable to edit them and change them completely.

Comment: Pertinent: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/262755)

Comment: +1 for asking but no, don't do that.

Comment: Also +1 for asking, and not just doing like some would. Do have a search around for other questions discussing how to fix bans etc. Plenty of info out there :) [Here's a starter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) :)

Comment: I'm trying - I'm making lots of useful edits and constructive comments.  I'm not sure I'm quite up to answering because I'm not an expert (which is why I need to ask questions).  I feel like editing my questions is the most useful thing I can do, but the questions I have don't give me much to work with.

Comment: +1 also for asking and having a very positive attitude (a very welcome change to some we see on here). I have upvoted one of your questions, I think the edits are looking good.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> should I edit the old questions I have and completely replace them with brand new questions?

No, you shouldn't do that. Especially if the question already has answers. You will be invalidating the work people have put in to help you. You shouldn't do it if the question was upvoted either.

The *only* time you could do this is if you have a zero scoring question with no answers, but don't be surprised if you get your edits rolled back.

What you should be doing is:

1. Answering other people's questions.
2. Editing your questions to **improve** them (but not rewrite them) so that they become better questions which attract upvotes.

You'll lift the ban by showing that you understand how the system works and that you can learn to produce good content.

Comment: about this point here Answering other people's questions. i have been banned forever now, because of some bad questions back when i was fresh now specially in the last month  i have been answering like crazy i gained about 800+ points in about month and that did not left up my ban so this point i am not very sure about it ... now when i fully understand the principles of good questions i CANT ask them :)) amazing mechanic .. i also edit a lot of new users and etc.. still banned i might not ask a question anytime soon but it seems unfair in the future when i need to ask one.

Comment: continue : shouldn't the "AUTO" system  recognize that a user has been answering and getting points etc..  and gained new medals privileges ..etc  is now a good question writer in general ?, i worked hard to get to the points i am at right now and its really unreasonable why a user can't ask even if he had bad ones in the past but when he reach some kind of point scale that indicates he is a "positive contributor" to the community

Comment: @Tobi - I don't know the internals of how question ban works (I assume I'm correct in which site your question blocked on), so I can't really offer any help other than what I've done here. If you really think the system is treating you harshly then use the contact us form to talk directory to the community team.

Comment: it is SO, and i have tried to contact them no response ..

Comment: should i post this as a discussion ?

Comment: @Tobi - I don't think a discussion would necessarily help. You could see if there are any chat rooms around the topics you are asking about and ask for help improving your existing questions there. I wouldn't ask on meta as that's not really what meta's for.

Comment: i really want to know how the system works ? and how it determine a "positive contributor" or not

Comment: @Tobi - Basically "positive contributions" are posts with a net positive score, it's as simple as that. The system takes deleted posts into account as well, so deleting your negatively scoring content isn't always the best thing to do.

Answer (score 11):

Those edits will just get rolled back, and if you continue to make those kind of edits anyway, you'll just end up finding a mod intervening and being forced to take an even more serious action.

Comment: Okay, so I'm new at programming, and some of my questions are not going to help anybody no matter how well they're edited.  How can I salvage terrible questions without completely changing them?

Comment: @brandaemon Being new to programming doesn't excuse asking bad questions.  The quality of a question is independent of the skill needed to solve it.

Comment: I'd argue that my knowledge of programming is somewhat pertinent because in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116996/what-is-the-cause-of-the-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error-in-c) for example no one could help me and I found a solution on accident.  From a programming perspective I still have no idea what went wrong.  I'd delete the question because I don't think it would help anyone but that would only make the ban worse.  I feel pressured to keep bad questions that I don't think could be improved.

Comment: @brandaemon: That's a poor example, since the question has an upvote and no downvotes. (And, from a cursory scan, appears to deserve that or perhaps a few more upvotes.)

Answer (score 2):

I actually got the ban lifted within a day or two of asking this question.  Like others have said, there was no need for drastic edits that change the nature of the questions asked.  Rather, all I needed to do was be patient as I contributed as honestly as I could to other aspects of StackExchange.

Despite this, I feel like the thing that most helped me was improving my old questions (without changing what was being asked, of course).  I feel that when a certain ban is placed on a user, that user should focus efforts on improving mostly in that area (especially by editing existing posts) to lift the ban, as per the instructions given in the link on the ban error page.